# c# .net WI-Fi discovery (windows user)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Can someone give me an example of how could I capture the Wi-fi from a zone? I am working on .net c# - mobile (sdk 6.5). I am working on vistual studio 2008.

Is there a library that can help me with this? I would appreciate if someone can give me an c# example. THx

Comment: Seems like you're trying to duplicate something that the device platform already does. Could you provide more info as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am using .net mobile. I want to make a programm that detects the wifi and gives you a list with all the wifi from your area. I am new in mobile and i don't know how to do it. Using the wifi i would like to for example send a request to a server.THx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Microsoft supplicant, you can use the [Automatic Configuration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925906.aspx) [WZCQueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910101.aspx) with INTF_BSSIDLIST and INTF_LIST_SCAN.

Otherwise, you will need to issue [NDIS IOCTL commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543936%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) like 
OID_802_11_BSSID_LIST_SCAN
OID_802_11_BSSID_LIST

For C# all of these methods will need to be pinvoked.

-PaulH